# JQuery Ajax Get Request to Parse API server with grouping

Tags: jquery, ajax, parse-platform

When making an ajax request to a Parse API server, is it possible to group the results on the server with out having to parse the data and group it in my client?

My code thus far is as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    // always use this url
    url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chatterbox',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'order=-createdAt',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        _.each(data.results, function(item){
            $('#messages').append('<li>'+item.text+'</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.error('chatterbox: Failed to send message');
    }
});
```

I am already ordering by date created.

```
"...",
data: 'order=-createdAt',
"..."
```

What would be nice is if I could add another data parameter to group results by a key on Parse, something like:

```
"...",
data: 'order=-createdAt,group=chatroom',
"..."
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `contentType; 'application/json'`. The data you're sending is `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I think you meant `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object or string or array in the data field, per the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
data: {"order":"-createdAt", "group": "chatroom"},
```